# Is there a way to programmatically set SSL as mandatory in Tomcat (e.g. not via web.xml)?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

We have a java web application which is deployed in many different clients using Tomcat 7. One of our clients wants us to make SSL mandatory, so that https is enforced. The other deployments should remain with no SSL since they don't have SSL certificates.

We know how to enforce it via security-constraint tags in web.xml, but we'd like to avoid the hassle of having to make a special build to a single client, and would rather be able to set this as a database parameter which would be read by the application and then programmatically enforce SSL or not.

Is this possible? How do we do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Jonathas

---

UPDATE: what we need is that in this specific environment the application automatically redirects por 80 to port 443, disabling port 80 is not a viable option.

Comment: Shouldn't it be fairly easy to build a universal `web.xml` template and then build each specific implementation out of the client's configuration?  I would say that would be the simplest way to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a filter that validates wether the connection is secure, via `ServletRequest.isSecure`. If not secure, and the application in context is one that requires a secure connection, then redirect to your 'https' endpoint. Otherwise, proceed.

Pseudocode:

```
public class SecureConnectionFilter implements Filter {
    private boolean requireSecure;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
            final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(requireSecure && ! (request.isSecure())) {
            // Redirect to secure endpoint
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request,  response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // Determine wether the application in context is required
        // to be secure or not. If this information is not available
        // at startup time then defer this logic to `doFilter`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for one client just comment out the plain http connector (and the corresponding port) in server.xml and leave only the secure connector and port available.
Simple solution, does not impact your code or other deployments and your client gets what he wants

**Update:**
You could redirect to https. Try:

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               redirectPort="443"/>
```

See this [also](http://www.itworld.com/development/79351/how-configure-tomcat-always-require-https)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm afraid this would make port 80 unavailable, but we need to enforce port 443 via redirection. I added an update to the question based on this.